# Is there a way to add a conditional statement within a variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `+ 450` to `var threshold` only if the page is `body.home`. So something like this:

```
var headHeight = jQuery('#masthead-space').height() + 23; 
var threshold =  jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').offset().top - headHeight (if body.home) + 450;

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold)
        jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').addClass('fixed');
    else
        jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with if body.home ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ternary operation (?:)

```
var threshold =  jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').offset().top - headHeight + (jQuery('body').hasClass('home') ? 450 : 0);
```

If I understand correctly `body.home` means **body element has a CSS class 'home'**.

To avoid performance impact use `jQuery(document.body)`

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this worked perfectly. I'll tick your answer once the time limit is up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using conditional/ternary operator:

```
var headHeight = jQuery('#masthead-space').height() + 23; 
var threshold =  jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').offset().top - headHeight + (body.home ? 450 : 0);
```

Comment: I was typing the same, and got notification 4 new answers :D

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var headHeight = jQuery('#masthead-space').height() + 23; 
var threshold =  jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').offset().top - headHeight + body.home ? 450 : 0 ;

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold)
        jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').addClass('fixed');
    else
        jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var threshold =  jQuery('.PopularTabsWidget').offset().top - headHeight +(body.home?450:0);
```